# Google Places API not returning place_id

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I've noticed the message about Google deprecating reference in favour of `place_id` and was looking to implement it.

I am using the [`AutocompleteService`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#place_autocomplete_service) but when I run it the response does not contain `place_id`, but does contain `reference` and `id`.

Here's a quick adaptation I did of the example page (I tried to put it on jsfiddle but couldn't get it to run):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Retrieving Autocomplete Predictions</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<script>
// This example retrieves autocomplete predictions programmatically
// from the autocomplete service, and displays them as an HTML list.
// The predictions will include a mix of places (as defined by the
// Google Places API) and suggested search terms.

function initialize() {
  var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
  service.getQueryPredictions({ input: 'trafalgar square' }, callback);
}

function callback(predictions, status) {
  if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    alert(status);
    return;
  }

  var results = document.getElementById('results');

  for (var i = 0, prediction; prediction = predictions[i]; i++) {
    results.innerHTML += '<li>' + prediction.description + '</li>';
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>

</head>
<body>
  <p>Query suggestions for 'trafalgar square':</p>
  <ul id="results"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone explain what I'm missing / doing wrong?

Has someone got an example of the `AutocompleteService` with `place_id` being returned with the predictions/suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue 6845
Bug: Google Maps JavaScript API - Autocomplete Response not included place_id

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6845&q=place_id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal

UPDATE

This issue has been fixed

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6845#makechanges

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm what you're seeing.  I'd guess we just need to wait for the roll out to be complete.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. It would be good to know whether Google have forgotten about the AutocompleteService on the maps API or whether they are still in the process of implmenting place_id values on all records.